# Inserting a VPN into a router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, vpn

Is it possible to have a router automatically use a VPN so that all of its users are on the VPN? The router is a TP-Link N600. Basically, once I connect to my Wi-Fi connction, I'd like everything to go through a VPN.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into DD-WRT (custom firmware) on your router - from what I can see it's supported on your router. This would allow you to configure a VPN provider directly on the router. Preventing you from having to install / run on individual devices or devices that don't allow you to install / run VPN software directly.

**NOTE: I have never installed or used it, just looked into it for my own circumstances. There a plenty of things that can go wrong and *according to their website* Incorrectly flashing can brick your router!**

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like you need an IPSEC 'tunnel', not 'transport'.

If your router does not provide you with the capability to create VPN tunnels then
I would suggest using a site-to-site IPSec VPN tunnel in Linux using Openswan, however this requires you have at least two nodes to create the connection, one at each end of the route you are trying to tunnel over. If you go for the Openswan solution your VPN will be transparent to your router, i.e it wont know about it nor care with the caveat that If you are facing problems with NAT, try using SNAT instead of MASQUERADING.

Also, some ISP's will filter IPSEC protocols/ports etc so you should be mindful of this when troubleshooting!

On another note, you might want to ** or obfuscate your IP information in trace routes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the router supports DD-WRT or equivalent  (and the TL-WDR3600 which TPLink describes as N600 does), then yes, you pretty much can do this.

In general terms, a VPN acts as a virtual interface, thus you can route all the traffic through the VPN rather then directly out the LAN Interface.  Note that traffic WITHIN your LAN will, of-course, not be encrypted by the VPN because it does not go through the router.

This is quite easy to do with DD-WRT and OpenVPN [ which of-course requires the VPN provider to support OpenVPN, but most do ], but any router which can act as a VPN client should do have this routing functionality as standard.